# Adding a populated existing disk device to a QEMU raw image

Tags: partition, dd, fdisk, qemu, parted

I have a raw QEMU image (vda.raw), and I would like to resize it and add an existing partition, using data I have in a file that contains a raw ext3 file system populated with data (vdb.raw). The two files look like this:

```
$ file vda.raw
vda.raw: x86 boot sector; partition 1: ID=0x83, active, starthead 0, startsector 16065, 20948760 sectors, code offset 0x63
$ file vdb.raw
vdb.raw: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=14555b9c-4837-4b43-a8e8-fe4e19194e88, volume name "ephemeral0" (large files)
```

Is there a simple way I can create a new image by combining these two: where the contents of vdb.raw appear as a new disk partition in vda.raw? I'd like to avoid having to:

1. Resize vda.raw
2. Create a new partition in vda.raw
3. Mount vda.raw
4. Mount vdb.raw
5. Copy the contents of vdb.raw into vda.raw

Is there a way I could, say, concatenate them with dd, and then fix the partition table to make it aware that there's a new partition in the image?

Comment: So, did this help out at all?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the obvious -- simply concatenating vdb to vda and creating a new partition?  I tried that and it seems to work.  Here's what I did...

I started with two files:

```
# ls -l vd*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 104857600 Feb 27 20:31 vda.raw
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 104857600 Feb 27 20:31 vdb.raw

# file vd[ab].raw
vda.raw: x86 boot sector; partition 1: ID=0x83, starthead 32, startsector 2048, 202752 sectors, extended partition table (last)\011, code offset 0x0
vdb.raw: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=734fa0ee-0bc8-4428-a13c-3147c9c0866f
```

The file `vda.raw` contains a standard partition map with a single partition (containing an ext3 filesystme):

```
# fdisk -l vda.raw 

Disk vda.raw: 104 MB, 104857600 bytes
191 heads, 50 sectors/track, 21 cylinders, total 204800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xad0a5dfe

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
vda.raw1            2048      204799      101376   83  Linux
```

`vdb.raw` contains an `ext3` filesystem.

First, we concatenate these two files together:

```
# cat vda.raw vdb.raw > combined.raw
```

Next, we create a new partition that covers the new data:

```
# fdisk combined.raw
```

Here's the initial partition table:

```
Command (m for help): p

Disk combined.raw: 209 MB, 209715200 bytes
191 heads, 50 sectors/track, 42 cylinders, total 409600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xad0a5dfe

       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
combined.raw1            2048      204799      101376   83  Linux
```

Now we create a new one, accepting the defaults for start sector and size:

```
Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (1 primary, 0 extended, 3 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 2): 2
First sector (204800-409599, default 204800): 
Using default value 204800
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (204800-409599, default 409599): 
Using default value 409599

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Syncing disks.
```

Now let's see what we've got:

```
# kpartx -a combined.raw 
# mkdir /mnt/{1,2}
# mount /dev/mapper/loop1p1 /mnt/1
# mount /dev/mapper/loop1p2 /mnt/2
# ls /mnt/1
lost+found  README.vda
# ls /mnt/2
lost+found  README.vdb
#
```

Ta-da!

Comment: I tried this, but fdisk hung when I tried to save the partition table (although I think that may have been unrelated, see 32921), but I wasn't able to mount the resulting combined image. So I just resized the first image, mounted both, and copied the files instead.